# Spring oauth intercept rest api calls and forward from one interceptor

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, oauth

I have configured all my spring security and oauth token getting etc

But do i have to validate the user from DB in each rest api call?

this is my example api:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUUID")
public Response getUUID(@Context HttpServletRequest request, final @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
    //here do i have to do this in each api or there is one filter that can i write and pass this user object from that to api
    User loadUser = loadUserFromSecurityContext(securityContext);
}

protected User loadUserFromSecurityContext(SecurityContext securityContext) {

    OAuth2Authentication requestingUser = (OAuth2Authentication) (securityContext).getUserPrincipal();
    String principal = requestingUser.getUserAuthentication().getName();
    User user = null;
    user = new UserDAO().getUser(principal);

    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept api call by implementing following filter:

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

AuthenticationManager authManager;

public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    this.authManager = authManager;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {        
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;

    //access your token here and do what you wanna do with it
    String authToken = httpServletRequest.getHeader("AUTHORIZATION");

    // continue thru the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

And in your spring-servlet.xml

```
<http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never" use-expressions="true"
      entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" class="com.yourpackage.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I have these exact setup, but the interceptor did not catch the request. Any idea ?